# Does Meteor lack the concept of well-defined data entity Models?

Tags: meteor

So, today was my second day learning Meteor.js - reading documentation, watching videos, etc...
What I did not see so far, was a strong concept of model, in a way that it would be used in most other JS frameworks. For example, if my Meteor app was to keep a list of people, I would declare a Collection of People, and, subsequently, add/update/remove Records to it. This to me is different from creating a Person object, setting its properties, adding that object to a collection of other Person objects, etc... Is my initial perception correct, and Meteor does not really have this paradigm of modeling business entities in a way that other frameworks do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out the minimongoid package on atmosphere

Comment: That particular package seems to be abandoned for now. It has not been updated in 5 months, and states that the tests do not run as of 0.6.5. There are, however, quite a few other ORM-type packages on Atmosphere that have more recent activity.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, either.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that's correct. This is a parallel to the schemaless nature of MongoDB, as opposed to a RDBMS where your data tables have an explicitly defined schema. Here's a quote from the Meteor docs under [`new Meteor.Collection()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection):

> Calling this function is analogous to declaring a model in a traditional ORM (Object-Relation Mapper)-centric framework.

However, Meteor does not prevent you from implementing your own more fully-fledged model system on top of the existing collection system. There are quite a few 3rd party packages on [atmosphere.meteor.com](http://atmosphere.meteor.com) that are attempting to do this. The [`transform` option on Meteor collections](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-transforming-collection-documents) gives a good starting point for creating a model layer, allowing you to add behavior and virtual fields to documents when they are retrieved from the database.

[Here's a roadmap entry](https://trello.com/c/jPrTL6n2/49-models-and-schemas) showing that models, schemas, validators, and migrations are planned in the future for Meteor. This is essential for [future SQL support](https://trello.com/c/Gf6YxFp2/42-sql-support). For 1.0 however, [they are trying to release a stable, thin core built on top of MongoDB](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/10/01/geoff-schmidt-at-devshop-8-getting-meteor-to-10). The MDG is no doubt watching the current model implementations on Atmosphere for inspiration to create their own core implementation later. [Geoff Schmidt briefly addressed this in the Getting Meteor to 1.0 video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ixt5MQBA5f8&t=29m11s)

TL;DR: Meteor provides the basic, essential APIs needed to implement models for MongoDB however you want. A more well-defined official data entity system and SQL support are planned for the future, but for now you can use 3rd party solutions on Atmosphere or roll your own.